# How can i installing Magento 2 with Sample data on my windows Xampp

Tags: magento2-dev-beta, sample-data, xampp

I successfully install Magento 2 without sample data on my windows Xampp
as following  process:

```
C:\Users\Matin>D:
D:\>cd D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2
D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2>
D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2>composer install

Then I install from browser as magento previous version..
```

Now How can i take sample data of my magento2 site.
I try to read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data.html#instgde-install-sample-intro
but Step 5 can not understandable for me

```
5.In the first section, add "minimum-stability": "beta", before license. A snippet follows:
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a pre stable version of Magento 2: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Answer (score 2):

Step 5 describes altering the composer.json file that came with your Magento 2. After adding `"minimum-stability": "beta",`, the top of the composer.json file should look similar to this:

```
{
    "name": "magento/magento2ce",
    "description": "Magento 2 (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "beta",
    "version": "1.0.0-beta",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
```

You would then continue by saving the file and performing step 7 in the [explanation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data.html#instgde-install-sample-enable-after) (execute `composer config repositories.magento composer http://packages.magento.com`). In step 8, execute `composer require magento/sample-data:~1.0.0-beta`. Wait for the process to finish installing the additional dependencies.

The final step would be to install the sample data itself. Run the magento executable in the bin folder of your Magento 2 installation like the following:

```
php magento setup:upgrade
php magento sampledata:install <your Magento administrator user name>
```

Installing the sample data can take a while.

Comment: where i add this line ? can u mention line number or before/after line

Comment: The composer.json file is in the root of your Magento installation. In my case I added it on line 5, just before the `"version"` field.